# Fill Gridview with SQL database

Tags: android, sql, listview, gridview

**EDIT: I'll use listview instead of Gridview. **

I've been learning Android since a couple of weeks and last days I've been struggling on getting my SQL-data in a gridview. I've been searching through many, many topics and I can't seem to find a fitting answer to my question. This is the code I've got so far:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        {
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
                    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
                    String subtitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subtitle"));

                    String name = id +"\n" + title +"\n"+ subtitle;
                    DisplayMessageActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + "'";

    public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";


        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
    DisplayMessageActivity.FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(this);

    public void Test (View view) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database you will actually use after this query.
        String[] projection = {MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE};

        // Filter results WHERE "title" = 'My Title'
        String selection = MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"A"};

        // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
        String sortOrder = MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

        Cursor c = db.query(
                MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                sortOrder                                 // The sort order
        );

        if (c.getCount()>0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int itemId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID));
            String strTitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
            String strSubtitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE));

            EditText edtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInvoer);
            edtID.setText(Integer.toString(itemId));

            EditText edtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitel2);
            edtTitle.setText(strTitel);

            EditText edtSubtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubtitel2);
            edtSubtitle.setText(strSubtitel);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geen data in db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public void Vorige (View view) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE};

        String selection = "_ID=?";
        EditText edtGeselecteerdeID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInvoer);
        int intVolgendeID=Integer.parseInt(edtGeselecteerdeID.getText().toString())-1;
        String strVolgendeID=Integer.toString(intVolgendeID);

        String[] selectionArgs = {strVolgendeID};

        // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
        String sortOrder = MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

        Cursor c = db.query(
                MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                sortOrder                                 // The sort order
        );


        if (c.getCount()>0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int itemId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID));
            String strTitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
            String strSubtitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE));

            EditText edtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInvoer);
            edtID.setText(Integer.toString(itemId));

            EditText edtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitel2);
            edtTitle.setText(strTitel);

            EditText edtSubtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubtitel2);
            edtSubtitle.setText(strSubtitel);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geen data in db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    public void Volgende (View view) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE};

        String selection = MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID + " = ?";
        EditText edtGeselecteerdeID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInvoer);
        int intVolgendeID=Integer.parseInt(edtGeselecteerdeID.getText().toString())+1;
        String strVolgendeID=Integer.toString(intVolgendeID);

        String[] selectionArgs = {strVolgendeID};

        // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
        String sortOrder = MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

        Cursor c = db.query(
                MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                sortOrder                                 // The sort order
        );


        if (c.getCount()>0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int itemId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID));
            String strTitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
            String strSubtitel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainActivity.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE));

            EditText edtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInvoer);
            edtID.setText(Integer.toString(itemId));

            EditText edtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitel2);
            edtTitle.setText(strTitel);

            EditText edtSubtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubtitel2);
            edtSubtitle.setText(strSubtitel);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geen data in db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }




}
```

So in MainActivity I've got code to add data into the database. 'DisplayMessageActivity' is for testing out new stuff. My database consists of 3 columns: ID, title and subtitle. I use the method 'Test' to display the data in Edittext objects, and the methods 'Vorige' and 'Volgende' to go through the data. Now I'm trying to display the data (id, title & subtitle) in a gridview or listview (I don't really know what to use). You can find all the code for my problem in the first onCreate class.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image]

So the first row displays the different column titles, and all the other rows display the data. **The first row displaying the titles aren't even needed, I could easily add them by using EditText fields.**

Can anyone help me out here? Other suggestions for improving my code are always welcome too ;)

Comment: then you need normal `ListView`, not `GridView`, since each row belongs to one item

Comment: Why not try making a Database helper class separately where you can first initialize the DB object with application context. You can then access the data by creating fetch method in the same helper class.

Comment: Alright I'll try that first. Do you have any suggestions for filling the listview?

Comment: read about `SimpleCursorAdapter`